# I can't figure out what my python book is asking me to do?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python, learning from a zybooks online book for college and i don't understand what this question is trying to get me to do. Here is the problem I am having:

Prompt:

Assign user_str with a string from user input, with the prompt: 'Enter a string:\n'

Reminder: The "\n" is a newline character that is not visible in the output and causes following output to appear on the next line.

Note: These activities may test code with different test values. This activity will perform two tests: the first with user input of "Hello!", the second with user input of "3230 Main St.". See How to Use zyBooks.

The code it gives me:

```
    print(user_str)
```

When I try to answer it, I get this error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Hello!'

help me??

Comment: show us what you tried

Comment: i basically tried to copy a previous example. I tried:         user_str = int(input('Enter a string:\n'))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can't tell you why code we can't see doesn't work like you expect. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading through the [help], particularly [ask], and then come back to [edit] your post.

Comment: @MeganMorris why do you think you need to do `int()` you are trying to get a string from the user, right? remove `int` and then see if it works

Comment: I am a complete python beginner I don't understand what's going on right now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MeganMorris Hey Megan, if you can maybe post which book, author, and page you are posting from we can maybe help explain the exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `foo = input("Enter string\n")` The text that the user enters is assigned to the value `foo` as **string**. If (as, I'm guessing you did in the previous example) you need to convert the string to and integer you need to do that explicitly with `int(foo)`.
If you don't need an integer, which you evidently don't, there's no need to convert it. Just use

```
user_str = input('Enter a string:\n')
```